# jquery to vanilla js ( I have a code which is about clipboard thing )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code written on jquery.

From https://gist.github.com/nicohaemhouts/0fa3ea89cad0b7d77648

This code is about pasting multiple line into input in html.

```
 if (window.clipboardData) {
    $('input[type=text]').on('paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(window.clipboardData.getData('Text').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "));
    });
}
```

`clipboardData` on first line is not existing in pure js.

Also, I can not understand Fourth line about jquery.

Can you please translate that jquery?

Comment: `$(this).val(x)` is equivalent to `this.value = x;`

Comment: Are you sure `window.clipboardData` is a jQuery thing? I don't think it is, there's a maybe related thing as standard API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData (looks like `window.clipboardData` might be an Internet Explorer thing)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).val(window.clipboardData.getData('Text').replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "));
```

`$(this)` refers to the input field element that caused this paste event, `.val` is used to set its value as the content of the clipboard, but before setting the value all newline symbols (`\n`) and carriage return symbols (`\r`) are replaced with space using `.replace`.